# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'

Tags: python

Estoy intentando crear la función suma pero puedo hacerlo para enteros o para listas, tuplas.

```py
#acepta enteros
def sumar (*lista):
  
  """
   sumo un conjunto de valores para una lista determinada

  """ 
  suma = 0 

  for i in lista:
    
      suma += i

  return suma
```

o en su defecto si quiero que lea tuplas o listas:

```py
def sumar_0 (lista):
  
  """
   sumo un conjunto de valores para una lista determinada

  """ 
  suma = 0 

  for i in lista:
    
      suma += i

  return suma
```

pero no estoy pudiendo integrar en la misma función ambas cosas

Comment: Y que le pasas como argumento? Cual es la entrada y salida esperada?

Answer (score 2):

Al usar la sintaxis `*lista` estás permitiendo que reciba cualquier número de parámetros, incluyendo uno solo. Eso te permite que la función primera haga lo que buscabas cuando le pasas una serie de enteros separados por comas, como en:

```py
>>> sumar(1,2,3,4)
10
```

pero "falla" cuando le pasas una lista de enteros así:

```py
>>> sumar([1,2,3,4])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'list'
```

La razón es que en este caso lo que recibes en `list` es un solo elemento, es decir `list[0]`, pero ese elemento es una lista y no un entero. Así, cuando intentas iterar para añadir a `suma` (que empieza valiendo 0), lo primero que añades es una lista, que no se puede sumar a un entero y de ahí el mensaje de error.

### Solución

El truco para dar con la solución es darse cuenta de que la función admite cualquier número de parámetros y de cualquier tipo, pero vamos a restringirlo a sólo dos posibles casos:

1. Lo que recibe es una serie de enteros, cualquier cantidad de ellos
2. Lo que recibe es  una lista o tupla, pero solo una (por tanto un solo prámetro)

Así que la función puede comenzar por mirar el tipo de su primer parámetro `list[0]`, según ese primer elemento sea iterable o no sabremos en cuál de los dos casos mencionados estamos.

Para ver si un dato es de tipo iterable es útil el módulo `collections.abc`. Además no necesitamos programar dos funciones separadas. En caso de que detectemos que etamos en el caso 2 (el iterable) basta que la función se llame a sí misma, pero desempaquetando ese iterable en una serie de argumentos separados por comas. Eso lo hace el operador `*`.

Por tanto el código sería:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

def sumar (*lista):
  """
   sumo un conjunto de valores para una lista determinada
  """
  if isinstance(lista[0], Iterable):
     return sumar(*lista[0])
  suma = 0 
  for i in lista:
      suma += i
  return suma
```

Demo:

```
>>> sumar(1,2,3,4)
10

>>> sumar([1,2,3,4])
10
```

### Bonus

Una vez hemos destapado la magia de la recursividad, no es muy difícil cambiar la función para que admita un mix de parámetros, algunos enteros, otros listas (incluso con listas dentro de listas) y que sea capaz de sumarlo todo "aplanando" las listas, es decir, fijándose sólo en los valores y no en su anidación. Para ello basta iterar por cada elemento `i` de la lista y si es un iterable, obtener su suma recursivamente y añadirla al acumulador `suma`, y si no es iterable sumarlo sin más a ese acumulador.

Es decir:

```py
def sumar (*lista):
  suma = 0 
  for i in lista:
    if isinstance(i, Iterable):
      suma += sumar(*i)
    else:
      suma += i
  return suma
```

Demo:

```
>>> sumar(1,2,3,4)
10

>>> sumar([1,2,3,4])
10

>>> sumar(1, [2, [3, 4]])
10
```